# How do I determine if the current user location is inside of my MKCoordinateRegion?

Tags: ios5, gps, mapkit, userlocation, mkcoordinateregion

I have a coordinate region that I have determined contains the limits of what I want to show for my app.  I have set this up as an MKCoordinateRegion with center point lat, longitude and a span.  How do I determine if the current userLocation is inside of my coordinate region?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use map rects.  Here's an example using the map's current visible rect.  With regards to your question, you could use `convertRegion:toRectToView:` to first convert your region to a `MKMapRect` beforehand.

```
MKMapPoint userPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate);
MKMapRect mapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;
BOOL inside = MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapRect, userPoint);
```

Comment: Ha, funny to get an answer so much later!  Thanks, a good answer so I'll go ahead and give you the mark -- the convertRegion:toRectToView is the thing I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 version of **firstresponder**'s answer:

```
let userPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(mapView.userLocation.coordinate)
let mapRect = mapView.visibleMapRect
let inside = MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapRect, userPoint)
```

Pretty much the same. This API has not been Swift-ified (i.e., updated to conform to the Swift API design guidelines) yet. It really *should* be...

```
let userPoint = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.mapPoint
let inside = mapView.visibleMapRect.contains(userPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to decide if a point is inside your area if the area is given by a polygon using the ray casting algorithm: See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

As a starting point use a location guaranteed to be outside your region, e.g. (geographic) north pole.

Comment: I was really looking for something in MapKit that would do the work for me!